# I’m wanting to find the equivalent of "describe history" for databricks in pyspark. Does such a thing exist?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

Title says it all really, I'm trying to find the latest version of a delta table but because im testing locally I dont have access to data-bricks.

Tried googling but not much luck im afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure SparkSession correctly as described in the [documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#-sql-support), then you can run SQL commands as well. But you can also access history using the Python or Scala APIs (see [docs](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#retrieve-delta-table-history&language-python)), like this:

```py
from delta.tables import *

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, pathToTable)
fullHistoryDF = deltaTable.history()
```